# Enable Chrome extension option "allow access to file urls" at domain level

Tags: file, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I understand that option can't be enabled by code, the extension user normally needs to enable that manually.

But if a domain admin uses Enterprise install to force install the extension in his domain, is there a way for the admin to enable that option?

Comment: Interesting question. I've never seen documentation pertaining to that, but can't say I'm sure it's impossible.

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: It's a bug and an old bug at that.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173640